# OCaml: Warning S: this expression should have type unit

Tags: ocaml

Code

```
Stack.pop some_stack;
```

generates "Warning S: this expression should have type unit.".
Is it possible to mute it without assigning result to some variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the ignore function with the result of the Stack.pop.

`ignore (Stack.pop some_stack);`

Comment: and get a habit to annotate the type of the `ignore`d expression :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the argument "-w -S" to ocamlc/ocamlopt to disable this warning. See the OCaml manual [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual022.html) and [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html).